# How to obtain HttpRequestMessage outside of controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, httprequest, owin

I have a Web API v2 controller that makes a method call out to a service in the same project. The service uses the `UrlHelper` class to put together a URL however, the UrlHelper class needs the `HttpRequestMessage` in order to build the proper URL.

How can I obtain the `HttpRequestMessage` from within a class (my service) that is outside of the API controller? Can I pass the `HttpRequestMessage` into the service method? Is there another way to access from a global context?

I am using a self-hosted environment (OWIN).

Comment: Static state is a bad idea - you should instead pass the `HttpRequestMessage` object, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Any idea how to grab the 'HttpRequestMessage' from the controoler?

Comment: There is a (not very nice, but possible) way, see this [SOA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776966/1138663)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult BarAction()
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = GetUrlHelperFromWhereever();
        urlHelper.DoSomething( this.Request );
    }
```

`this.Request` is HttpRequestMessage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.request(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Request